# Unexpected Consistent Network Device Name on Linux

Tags: linux, networking

I have a single SSD disk with minimal linux installed, where I configured GRUB to boot linux (kernel version 4.15.0) with the Consistent Network Device Naming feature enabled (by setting `net.ifnames=1`). I put this SSD into two PCs which are almost identical (same main board, just a slightly different processor version). On both I run `lshw -class network`.

Output on PC1:

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: 00:13:95:2a:e4:5c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.2-4 ip=192.168.0.171 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:126 memory:df200000-df21ffff
```

Output of PC2:

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno1
       version: 10
       serial: 00:13:95:33:8c:4c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.5-4 ip=192.168.0.171 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:126 memory:a1300000-a131ffff
```

Both of them have the ethernet adapter on PCI bus `00:1f.6`. On PC1 the interface is named `enp0s31f6`, which I expected. But on PC2 it is named `eno1`, which quite confuses me.

So two questions:

- Why are they named differently? I used the same SSD on both, so software configuration is exactly the same.
- Is it possible to enforce the usage of the name based on PCI location (`enp0s31f6`)?

`biosdevname` is not installed (which should use `emX` name anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short `eno#` and `ens#` names are generated based on slot information provided by your **firmware**: the `o` indicates onboard LAN ports while `s` indicates hotplug slot numbers. See the manual page [systemd.net-naming-scheme](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.net-naming-scheme.html) for more detail (currently online-only, new in v243).

([udev-builtin-net_id](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v242/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_id.c) obtains the slot information primarily from `/sys/class/pci/slots`, which is documented as "ACPI _SUN - slot user number". The onboard index is read from `/sys/class/net/eth0` attributes `device/acpi_index` (ACPI _DSM), `device/index` (SMBIOS), `dev_port`, `phys_port_name`.)

To force names based on PCI topology, use systemd.link(5) to set the name policy to `path`,

```
# /etc/systemd/network/50-names.link

[Match]
OriginalName=*

[Link]
NamePolicy=keep path
# Default is "keep kernel database onboard slot path"
# (set in /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link)
```

...or use an udev rule in 81-something.rules to assign `NAME="$env{ID_NET_NAME_PATH}"` to network interfaces (you shouldn't need to do this as udev always reads the .link files):

```
# /etc/udev/rules.d/81-net-names.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ENV{ID_NET_NAME_PATH}=="?*", NAME="$env{ID_NET_NAME_PATH}"
```

Comment: the .link file works great, thanks! Out of curiosity I also tried to do it the other way around (forcing the eno* or ens* names) by putting `onboard` and `slot` as first entries in the `NamePolicy` on the PC which always had the path based name, which did not work. Did those policies just fail and the next in the list was used instead (as described in the documentation you linked)?

Comment: Yes, they just failed because the other PC's firmware did not supply the information. There's no point in trying to force udev into using something that doesn't exist. (This info is mostly obtained from ACPI tables, so if the motherboards are identical, it might be that the firmware version is different.)